# XSLT if body has a class then do something

Tags: xslt

I'd like my xslt to show some html depending on whether the class of "video" displays on the body tag. Is this possible? For many reasons, I can't use Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:if test="contains(/html/body/@class, 'video')">
</xsl:if>
```

Of course, this will also evaluate to true for `my-video` and other classes. If such collisions are possible, consider using

```
<xsl:if test="/html/body/@class = 'video' or
              contains(/html/body/@class, ' video ' or
              starts-with(/html/body/@class, 'video ' or
              ends-with(/html/body/@class, ' video')">
</xsl:if>
```

If using XSLT 2.0, you can also use the `matches()` function

Comment: Somewhat more concisely, you could also do `<xsl:template match="body[@class='video']">`.

Answer (score 4):

**In XSLT one can avoid almost completely explicit conditional instructions:**

```
<xsl:template match=
  "/html/body[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' video ')]">
 <!-- Wanted processing here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, in order to be selected for execution, this template needs to match a node from the node-set specified in the select attribute of a corresponding `<xsl:apply-templates>` -- either explicitly or as part of the XSLT default processing (as part of a built-in XSLT template).

Comment: That's pretty slick. I hadn't thought of adding the extra whitespace to the `@class`...

Comment: @LukasEder, Yes, this is a very powerful and *generic* principle -- it is called *sentinel programming*. I saw it mentioned first in Jon Bentley's book "Programming Pearls".